# Select tag options style

Tags: html, css, select

I have this default options tag, but I need these to somehow get. Does somebody know to style this things.
[this is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQC5B.png)
[This is what I need to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML2qj.png)

This is my code:

```
<label class="mt-4 mb-1" for="type-students">Тип на студенти</label>
            <select id="type-students" name="type-students">
              <option value="" disabled selected hidden>
                Изберете тип на студент
              </option>
              <option value="marketing">Студенти од маркетинг</option>
              <option value="coding">Студенти од програмирање</option>
              <option value="data-science">Студенти од data-science</option>
              <option value="design">Студенти од дизајн</option>
            </select>
```

```
label {
  display: block;
}

input,
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.5em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

select {
  padding: 26px 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

input:focus,
select:focus {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px red;
}
```

I tried looking on Google and Stack Overflow, but I can't find anything. Any help will be very helpful.

Comment: You can't style `<select>` elements like that. It's entirely up to the browser. The only alternative is to use JS to create _replacement HTML_ for the `<select>`.